# How to exclude or ignore special paths or routes from zuul routing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

Is it possible to exclude paths or matchers from the Zuul routing?

The goal is that

- All requests to */contracts/*** are routed to *contract.example.com*
- All requests to */audit/*** are routed to *audit.example.com*
- All requests to */heartbeat/*** or */sso/*** are served from zuul directly.
- All other requests (*/***) are routed to *html.example.com*

I have configuration like this:

```
zuul:
    routes:
        contract:
            path: /contracts/**
            url: http://contracts.example.com:8080/api
        audit:
            path: /audits/**
            url: http://audit.example.com:8080
        html:
            path: /**
            url: http://html.example.com:80
```

Now the question is how to define that */heartbeat* and */sso* isn't routed to *html.example.com* by zuul?

I'm using Spring Boot and its AutoConfiguration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a configuration property called *ignored-patterns*. With this it is possible to define matchers to exclude routes from routing.

```
zuul:
    ignoredPatterns:
        - /heartbeat/**
        - /sso/**
    routes:
        contract:
            path: /contracts/**
            url: http://contracts.example.com:8080/api
        audit:
            path: /audits/**
            url: http://audit.example.com:8080
        html:
            path: /**
            url: http://html.example.com:80
```

Comment: Apparently it is `ignoredPatterns`, not `ignored-patterns`

Comment: Zuul does not accepts ignoredPatterns values listed as sequence. Its values should be comma separated, like ignoredPatterns: value1, value2, value3 , as it is implemented as LinkedHashSet

Comment: @Shafiul is correct, this is still true as of `Brixton.SR6` release: `ignoredPatterns: /foo/**,/bar/**`

Answer (score 3):

As of `Brixton.SR6` the ignoredPattern properties should be defined different in the `application.yml` file. It should be defined as follows:

```
zuul:
ignoredPatterns: /heartbeat/**, /sso/**
routes:
    contract:
        path: /contracts/**
        url: http://contracts.example.com:8080/api
```