# How to ignore a route in zuul?

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul

I have a spring application, in which I use zuul for routing. My routing configuration is like this:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    core:
      path: /core/**
      url: http://localhost:3002
    ui:
      path: /**
      url: http://localhost:3003
```

Now I defined a rest controller in my app, and it should serve the captcah service beside its routing. So I used `ignored-services: /captcha/**` and even `ignored-patterns: /captcha/**`

But it don't work and requests for captcah are routed to the `ui` path.

My using zuul version is: `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.0.3.RELEASE`

Comment: This perhaps helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167629/how-to-exclude-or-ignore-special-paths-or-routes-from-zuul-routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its ignoredPatterns instead of ignored-pattern

```
zuul:
    ignoredPatterns:
        - ...........
routes:
core:
  path: /core/**
  url: http://localhost:3002
ui:
  path: /**
  url: http://localhost:3003
```